# No puedo hacer un Web Scraping en una página web

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-scrapping

He estado intentando hacer un web scraping en este sitio web `https://www.segundamano.mx/anuncios/ciudad-de-mexico/alvaro-obregon/venta-inmuebles/casas`, usé una función empleando Bs4 como se muestra a continuación:

```
def scrape_page(page_url):
    answer = requests.get(page_url)
    content = answer.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features='html.parser')
    return soup


soup = scrape_page('https://www.segundamano.mx/anuncios/ciudad-de-mexico/alvaro-obregon/venta-inmuebles/casas')
print(soup)
```

El objeto soup me devuelve el texto HTML pero de forma extraña.

[image: Soup]

Cuando intento extraer elementos obtengo un objeto vacío:

```
elements_found = texto.find_all('p', class_='card-data-bottom-container-price')
```

Los tags y class aparecen en la página web, pero en la sopa solo aparece la información mas no los tags, quería saber si hay otra forma de hacer ese web scraping.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Voté pa reabrir. Hasta tengo una respuesta pa poner, jeje :)

Comment: Aaaabraaaaan la preguntaaaaa

Comment: Meh. En fin. La solución pasa por no usar requests ahí sino `content=urllib.urlopen(url).read()`, con eso te queda algo que ese parser puede procesar

Comment: Hola, metí solicitud para que reabran la pregunta hace unos días pero no me han contestado, independientemente de eso gracias por tu respuesta intentaré hacer eso

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando urllib en vez de requests. Queda más a la mano un resultado que el parser html de bs4 puede procesar.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape_page(page_url):
    content = urlopen(page_url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    return soup

soup = scrape_page('https://www.segundamano.mx/anuncios/ciudad-de-mexico/alvaro-obregon/venta-inmuebles/casas')
print(soup.prettify())
```